# Co-worker tells me he cannot keep up

Tags: professionalism, team, performance, colleagues

I got something like this from a co-worker:

> I can no longer keep up 
>   with things here. I just don't know how to approach tasks and I also have now clue how to catch up with things here.

To me, this really sounds like "inner resignation" and I already told my boss about that, but nothing happend yet.

Till now, I was giving him advice and assigned tasks to him that are important for us right now, but his performance continues to be inferior compared to other co-workers.

On the other hand, I don't think my co-worker is totally aware of his (serious) situation.

How can I help my coworker improve?

1. Just do nothing is perfectly viable for me at this point, as my boss is aware of this.
2. Talk to my coworker and ask him, what he wants to do in the future? I.e. making him aware that he already resigned sort of.
3. Continue to support him by mentoring, providing ideas and guidelines.
4. Getting HR involved. And then bad things will happen.

Some additional information:

1. I'm just a co-worker that knows some details.
2. He is a peer, but a junior from a technical pov.
3. I won't involve HR.

Comment: Are you this person's manager, or are you responsible for assigning them tasks? Why are they coming to you with this issue?

Comment: Is this person a peer, or junior?

Comment: Why would you involve HR here? What do you imagine they could possibly do? Performance issues are what *managers* are for. /// Someone who's writing stuff like this down is likely aware that it's a serious situation. ///  Why do you feel compelled to act? To mentor? Because it's causing issues for your work? Some other reason?

Comment: This is a management issue. I would recommend that you let your junior talk to your manager and let them sort it out. I think your best way to help is your  #3. Perhaps talk to him and see why he feels that way and provide any resources/help necessary.

Comment: While I fell we need to know more about you and coworker raltionship (leader, manager/ intern for example). As a human being and professional I can fell compeled to try a few words of advice for him and even try to glimpse the origin of such melancholy, maybe it's a symptom of depression and must be addressed by a md. That said maybe the best option is to advice your coworker to seek professional help anyway (a doctor or some sort of personal RH consultor from outside your company)

Comment: @Lilienthal - can't speak for the OP (well I can but i'd be risking talking BS), but I have frequently ran into situations like this where there WAS an impact to team-mates in terms of higher workloads including having to fix what the other person broke.

Comment: I mostly agree with @jean, though it might not even be something as grave as depression. It could be that this person is coming to the realization that their current job isn't in harmony with career aspirations. Lots of people go through that and it could manifest as anything from self-doubt to mental nausea at the amount of unrewarding work in front of them. A supportive coworker should try to assess and help out, but be aware that no intervention will work if the person truly needs a change of job or career-path.

Comment: Good grief. Sounds like coming to you for some help might have been no different than stepping on a landmine. HR?

Comment: @L0j1k, you're right. Asking the "wrong" coworker for help can be very harmful to one's career. I've seen it before in real life and in here. Especially in some technical fields where empathy is in short supply, folks are apt to run to the boss/HR for the most trivial of problems. Trust is the most critical prerequisite before asking for help from anyone.

Answer (score 27):

Assuming you want to grow your coworker into a valuable teammate and colleague, there are some things you can do.

The first thing to realize is it seems that your coworker is suffering from both a crisis of confidence and motivation.  The best way I have found to address that is to give them small wins.  Cut some simple, small achievable tasks and assign them to your coworker.  This will give them a small boost of confidence and make them feel like they are contributing even if it is a not at as high of level as they would like.

Set aside some time, I prefer 2 hours chunks a few times a week, to do some pair programming on some more complex tasks.  You will probably have to start off in the lead, but you need to actively get direction from your coworker.  The goal here is to again build their confidence in their ability to problem solve, and to develop their skills.  So it is important that they contribute.  You should at some point transition to where they are driving the programming sessions and you are helping to contribute to their work.

When they get assigned a new task that they say is over their head, break down the task with them.  Help them chew it in manageable chunks.  Then follow up on their progress with each step.  You may even need to help show them some techniques to solve some of the steps and that is ok.  It is also ok for them to fail to complete a task if they tried it.  But you can not let them sit there floundering for days and not expect them to regress.  You have to stay engaged with them, and keep them moving.

Answer (score 18):

**HR IS NOT YOUR FRIEND**

Getting them involved will also get you personally involved.

This is a matter for your manager to deal with, not you and going to HR will likely be seen as going behind your manager's back and might get **YOU** put on the short list for being let go.

You have reported up to your manager, that is the end of your obligation.  If your coworker reaches out to you again, just tell that coworker to talk to the manager.  Remove yourself from the situation entirely and worry about your own work.  Anything else could have a negative impact on your own career.

Comment: @curiousdannii I think HR exist mostly to advise the company on how to hire and fire people without getting sued.

Answer (score 5):

Try not to get too involved. Intervening with your co-worker's self-doubt may not prove very productive, and so option #1 is your best bet. Here's an analysis of the four options you listed:

1. Doing nothing is, as you said, perfectly viable. It requires no additional effort and no risk on your part. Admittedly this is not a particularly sympathetic solution, but it seems fine considering this co-worker is not your responsibility. Besides, if the job is a bad fit, then perhaps leaving and moving on to another position could benefit them in the long run. **This is your most rational option of the four.**
2. Talking to your co-worker about their future plans is a nice balanced strategy, where you are showing sympathy and being helpful, without significant risk for yourself. Having someone to talk to could help them prioritize their goals, and possibly improve their performance. Just try to keep the discussion informal, and don't commit too much of your work time to these talks. You're not in a position to manage them or dictate what they should do.
3. Serving as this co-worker's mentor is kind, but unwise. You risk placing yourself to accept additional responsibility that you don't need and you don't want. If you genuinely think they have the potential to improve their performance and contribute more, then you could recommend some strategies or resources. But it's not your job to guide them or train them, especially if they consistently anchor the team's progress.
4. Nothing good will be achieved by involving HR. Contacting HR yourself can and will pull you in to however the company decides to handle your co-worker. Also, this scenario doesn't seem to warrant HR intervention. The co-worker's performance issues are best handled by the project manager or their immediate manager, not you and certainly not HR.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say your best options are either one or three.  You're not his manager, so it's not your duty to talk to HR.  If you like this co-worker or think he has potential, you might try to continue to mentor him, however in the end, only he is responsible for his success.

Firing an employee is never a good thing and should be seen as a failure of management.  The manager either failed by hiring the wrong person or by failing to give him the right motivation and mentorship for success.  If you think you are capable of turning him around, you would be doing your manager a great service.  Just make sure you keep your manager informed about everything you do and don't take anything into your own hands.  Also, make sure you don't forsake your own duties by trying to fix a weak link in the chain.

From what you say, it sounds like this person has a bad attitude and I wouldn't want to associate with someone who complains about his situation instead of looking for ways to improve, but in the end, it's up to you.  If you aren't sure, ask your manager what to do.

Whatever you do, avoid any situations where management might use collective pronouns to refer to the two of you in a negative way.  "*They* failed to complete this project.  *They're* performance is suffering," etc.  On the other hand, comments like "[co-worker] was failing to live up to expectations but user78206 helped him get up to speed" could be very good for you.